# Inno Setup: uninstall process can't remove MSIMG32.DLL from {app} folder whatever I do

Tags: dll, inno-setup

What kind of magic has this 'MSIMG32.DLL'? Why can't inno setup delete it?

Edit: this file was just added to {app} using [File] section, at the end of uninstall I get the message "Some elements could not be removed. These can be removed manually." what is referred to MSIMG32.DLL exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should you have this file in your installation set ? This is a Windows image dll ? Remove it from the [Files] section.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I really don't need this file.

Comment: @Alex: Maybe you would be so kind as to mark my answer as the selected one ?

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps likely that that DLL is in use by some running application.  There is an [addon](http://raz-soft.com/display-english-posts-only/files-in-use-extension-for-inno-setup/) for InnoSetup that deals with this situation.  There is not enough information in the question from which other ideas may be produced.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that, on your system, that file either is, or has been infected by a virus, as suggested by [ThreatExpert](http://www.threatexpert.com/files/msimg32.dll.html).  You should exclude that possibility by running a system scan with your anti-virus program.